# Corona sdk - displaying image inside a text body

Tags: sdk, coronasdk

I am using the corona sdk to create a list of items in a tableview, once and item is selected I then display a bio for that item, and also want to display an image.

I can do this fine, but how can I right align the image in the body of text and get the text like flow round the image? I am using native.newText to display the text.

Similar to having a right aligned image inside a

tag in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that automatically, you need to detect the image dimensions (I suggest using myImage.contentBounds ) then place the text near it as you wish.

In a app of mine we display a picture, some basic data, and a detailed description, what I do is put the picture, then place the basic data to its right, and then place the detailed description below both.